# Bind Model with the ViewModel in WPF Prism

Tags: wpf, prism

Assume I create a bunch of Model classes dynamically (say based on some config file content on startup), say each model is an instance of a class CarModel:

```
public class CarModel
{
    public string CarName { get; private set; }


    public CarModel(string carName)
    {
        CarName = carName;
    }
}
```

All of them then added to ObservableCollection CarList, and then represented in the view in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:CarModel}">
        <views:CarView></views:CarView>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CarList}">
</ListBox>
```

I then bind CarView to CarViewModel through the Prism AutoWireViewModel.
I use CarViewModel because I have bunch of extra (only view related) properties, and also handle navigation and events (through eventAggregator) that I don't want to include in my original CarModel.

My problem is, how do I bind (or link) my **CarViewModel** with the original **CarModel** that created the view?

Comment: Why do you need to know which dto a viewmodel was created from? Can't you just build a dto from the viewmodel and use that for a service call or EF or sql?

Comment: @AndrejsGasilovs: Why would you want to use an auto wired view model in this case? The view should bind directly against the `CarModel`. Maybe you should change its name to `CarViewModel` and/or merge the existing `CarViewModel` and `CarModel` classes together.

Comment: @mm8 I could, but then CarViewModel get's too big and we move from MVVM to VVM. I was trying to separate the logic and see whether this is going work or not, before rethinking the design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I bind (or link) my CarViewModel with the original CarModel that created the view?

Either by navigating to the view and passing the respective model in the navigation parameters or (preferredly) by creating the view model yourself (through a factory) instead of using the view model locator and initializing it with its model.

That is, `CarList` should be contain `CarViewModel`s. If you need full two-way synchronization (the list is changed by the database and the view simultaneously), this means a lot of boilerplate code, but most of the time, you need no synchronization at all... so a `IReadOnlyColletion<CarViewModel` suffices (instead of a full-blown `ObservableCollection`) and it can be initialized once with a simple `Select`.

Hint: the view model locator is meant for top-level views mainly, most of the time you're better off creating the view model and linking it to the view with a `DataTemplate`, i.e. going view model-first. In fact, earlier version of prism supported this approach even when navigating regions, and dropping that made regions far less widely usable sensibly.

Comment: Thanks, could you please elaborate on the IReadOnlyColletion and using Select for initialization?

Comment: something like `CarList = _repository.Cars.Select( x => _carViewModelFactory.Create( x ) ).ToArray();` in the constructor to initialize the property `public IReadonlyCollection<CarViewModel> CarList { get; }`